# Always affect Row in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP, I'm using mysqli_affected_rows to validate whether a user has been registered in a database, where a query looks something like this:

```
"UPDATE schedule WHERE userid = '$user' AND date='2018-05-05'"
```

If the user doesn't exist, the number of affected rows is 0, and if they do exist, it's 1.

This works OK, except for when a user is registered in a second time. Here, MySQL will say 0 rows are affected, since there has been no *change* to the schedule.

Is there anything I can add to my query to always affect rows? Or is this just a poor approach?

Comment: What are you updating on schedule table for the particular user?

Comment: It's an app for students and teachers. A teacher inputs a list of student IDs, and the program updates the students log for that day to that teacher's ID. So only the 'location' field is altered

Answer (score -1):

To check whether a user exists in a database, I would use a select statement instead.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE userid = '$user' AND date='2018-05-05'"
```

Then do something if a user exists

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
//user exists 
}
```

I would also assume you would like to have unique users in the database? I that case I would check whether a user exists first using the same code before adding a new record.

Comment: Well the idea is that users from a given list are checked in to a schedule, so their location is updated based on the current date. Then the mysqli_affected_rows() will show whether or not the user exists. If I did another SELECT query, it would double the amount of time the script takes, and for long lists this could be porblematic

Comment: @CurtisUpsall Don't do this. It's a bad idea.